# How other users will connect to my dropbox application?

Tags: vb.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

Scenario: I want to create a vb.net application which will automatically upload a backup file to my clients' dropbox account. So each of my client will be able to use my app and upload the backup file o their own dropbox account.

Steps I already did:

1. I have created an application on Dropbox in App Console area.
2. I have edited the permissions which my app will need.
3. I have generated my access token from my app Panel (lest name it dx)
4. Using visual studio (and vb.net language) I created the code below(Imports Dropbox.Api, System.IO are needed)

   ```
       Public Class Form1
       Public dbx = New DropboxClient("myAccessToken")

       '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Upload File Button
       Private Sub btnUploadFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadFile.Click
           Dim task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(CType(AddressOf UploadFile, Func(Of Task)))
           task.Wait()

   End Sub
   '~~~~~~~~Code to upload the file on dropbox account
   Public Async Function UploadFile() As Task
           Await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(DropboxPath & FileName, body:=(New FileStream(LocalPath & FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
       End Function

   End Class
   ```

Until here everything work great! (and i can successfully upload a file to my dropbox)

But now, I am confused about how my app users will work with my application and for the further steps.

I know that I have to "Apply my App for Production", but after what?

I have read many articles but still confused about the way.

Is there any simple way to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use a generated access token to test against your own Dropbox account, in order to have arbitrary end-users connect their accounts to your app, you'll need to implement the OAuth app authorization flow. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization).

For [the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet), you can find examples of using the OAuth flow in [the OauthBasic example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/main/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/OauthBasic/Program.cs) (non-PKCE, meant for server-side apps) as well as in [the OAuthPKCE example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/main/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/OAuthPKCE/Program.cs) (PKCE, meant for client-side apps).